# Apache2 | New images are only showing on the ubuntu web browser

Tags: server, apache2

I'm a noob to this kind of stuff
and i changed some images around in my apache2 server but if i look at the page from a windows pc the images are the original but if i load the page on the ubuntu pc that is hosting the website/server it shows the new image. why is it doing this and how can i fix this?

PS the image names are correct.

Website Code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>yeTensziWorld-Servers</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Mine-Strap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/CandyUI.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mine-strapUI.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Lato:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic","PT Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic","Raleway:100,200,300,regular,500,600,700,800,900"]
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/300_1.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/300_1.png">
</head>
<body class="body">
  <div class="w-section image-section">
    <div class="w-container image-section-container">
      <a href="#" id="top" class="w-inline-block link-top"></a>
      <div data-collapse="none" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" data-contain="1" class="w-nav navigation">
        <div class="w-container">
          <div class="w-row w-hidden-medium">
            <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny left"><a href="#Features" class="w-nav-link nav-link">about</a>
            </div>
            <div class="w-col w-col-2 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny left-middle"><a href="#Staff" class="w-nav-link nav-link">staff</a>
            </div>
            <div class="w-col w-col-4 navigation-centre"><a href="#top" class="w-nav-link w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny nav-link centre">top</a>
            </div>
            <div class="w-col w-col-2 right-middle"><a href="#Rules" class="w-nav-link w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny nav-link">rules</a>
            </div>
            <div class="w-col w-col-2 right"><a href="#Voting" class="w-nav-link w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny nav-link">Vote</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h1 class="heading white">yeTensziWorld Friendly Game Servers!</h1>
      <p class="paragraph white">Terraria, Minecraft and CSGO</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section about-section">
    <div class="w-container about-section-container">
      <a href="#" id="Features" class="w-inline-block link-features"></a>
      <h1 class="heading prism">Servers</h1>
      <div class="w-row about-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-4 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny"><img src="images/rocket.png" class="about-image">
          <h1 class="about-heading">Terraria</h1>
          <p class="about-para">Great Friendly Community with Protection and great survival gameplay!&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-4"><img src="images/Globe.png" class="about-image">
          <h1 class="about-heading">Minecraft</h1>
          <p class="about-para">Friendly Communinty with Creative for the builders, games for the fighters and survival for the brave.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-4"><img src="images/Star.png" class="about-image">
          <h1 class="about-heading">CSGO</h1>
          <p class="about-para">Great surf server with yet again a friendly community and tons of great maps you'd wanna play!</p>
          <img src="images/Globe.png" class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium about-image">
          <h1 class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium about-heading">Unique</h1>
          <p class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium about-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium mobile-join-us"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny popup">
    <div class="w-container popup-container">
      <h1 class="heading white popup-title">Access the Forums!</h1>
      <p class="popup-para">Goto our Forums to submit feedback and messages!</p><a href="forums" class="w-button popup-button forums">Access the Forums</a><a href="forums"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section staff-section">
    <div class="w-container staff-section-container">
      <a href="#" id="Staff" class="w-inline-block link-staff"></a>
      <h1 class="heading prism">Server Staff</h1>
      <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-4 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny"><img src="images/300.png" class="staff-head">
          <h1 class="staff-heading">yeTenszi</h1>
          <p class="staff-postion"><em data-new-link="true">Server Owner</em>
          </p><img src="images/256 (1).png" class="staff-head _2nd-row">
          <h1 class="staff-heading">Alek09</h1>
          <p class="staff-postion"><em data-new-link="true">Server Admin</em>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-4 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny"><img src="images/300 (1).png" class="staff-head">
          <h1 class="staff-heading">Staff Position</h1>
          <p class="staff-postion"><em data-new-link="true">Server Admin</em>
          </p><img src="images/300 (3).png" class="staff-head _2nd-row">
          <h1 class="staff-heading">Staff Position</h1>
          <p class="staff-postion"><em data-new-link="true">Server Moderator</em>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-4 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny"><img src="images/300 (4).png" class="staff-head">
          <h1 class="staff-heading">Staff Position</h1>
          <p class="staff-postion"><em data-new-link="true">Server Admin</em>
          </p><img src="images/256.png" class="staff-head _2nd-row">
          <h1 class="staff-heading">Staff Position</h1>
          <p class="staff-postion"><em data-new-link="true">Server Moderator</em>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" id="Features" class="w-inline-block link-features"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny rules-section">
    <div class="w-container w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny">
      <a href="#" id="Rules" class="w-inline-block link-rules"></a>
      <h1 class="heading white server-rules">Server Rules</h1>
      <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-3">
          <h1 class="rules-number">1</h1>
          <h1 class="rule-heading">Griefing</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny">
          <h1 class="rules-number">2</h1>
          <h1 class="rule-heading">Cussing</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny">
          <h1 class="rules-number">3</h1>
          <h1 class="rule-heading">Advertising</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-3">
          <h1 class="rules-number">4</h1>
          <h1 class="rule-heading">Hacks</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny server-voting">
    <a href="#" id="Voting" class="w-inline-block link-voting"></a>
    <h1 class="heading white voting">Server Voting</h1>
    <p class="voting-para">Vote and you may just get some sleek gear!</p>
    <div class="w-container">
      <div class="w-row voting-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-4"><a href="#" class="w-button vote-button">1</a>
          <p class="rules-para">PlanetMinecraft.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-4"><a href="#" class="w-button vote-button">2</a>
          <p class="rules-para">Minecraft-Servers.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-4"><a href="#" class="w-button vote-button">3</a>
          <p class="rules-para">Server-list.org</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny footer">
    <div class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny copyright-text">Copyright 2016 - Developed by SONNIX.NET - Version 2.2</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was your **cache memory and cookies**.

Kindly remove everything otherwise use private window browser.

Comment: Cheers Mate this fixed my problem!

Comment: Also i can tell you're australian like me with that woolworths icon. XD